# Resize and save image on the phone at url not working

Tags: swift, image, uiimage, resize

on my project I use the following method to resize the image "UIimage":

```
func resizedAutomatic() -> UIImage? {
        var image: UIImage = self
        while image.size.width > 800 || image.size.height > 800 {
            
            let newdim = CGSize(width: image.size.width/1.5, height: image.size.height/1.5)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newdim, false, 0)
            defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newdim))
            image =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? self
        }
        return image
      }
```

I then save it locally on the phone with the following method:
("for easy explanation I delate part of the code in the method")

Save the picture locally:

```
func saveImage(project: Project?,picFrame: CGSize?,image: UIImage?,bbox:[PathContainer], closure: @escaping (_ project : Project)->()){
    print("DEBUG 1-----Receive immagine in save \(image?.size)") // size is correct 
    guard let project = project else {
        return
    }
    if let image = image {
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            print(" DEBUG 2__ saving check size \(image.size)") // size is correct
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("pictures", isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(project.id.uuidString)
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filename.path) { // se non esiste la cartella picture crea.
                
                do {
                    
                    let countPic = getCountFoto(project: project) + 1
                    project.counter = countPic
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: filename.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    let loc = filename.appendingPathComponent("\(countPic).jpeg")
                    //___ something wrong ---------------------- size of the picture is not correct
                    try? data.write(to: loc) // SAVE PICTURE HERE
                    print("saved at \(filename)")
                    let kb = Double(data.count) / 1000.0
                    let mb = Double(kb) / 1000.0
                    print("actual size of image in KB: %f ", kb)
                    print("actual size MB", mb)
                    
                } catch {
                    print("ERRRRRR")
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
          
        }
    }
}
```

After I run this method I'm expecting to find in the hard disk the image resize.. something like 500px X 500 px but I'm finding the jpeg picture with size not changed  for example 'height: 2390 px width: 1792 px'..
what I don't understand is my debug DEBUG print 1/2 print the size correctly but the 'try? data.write(to: loc)' save the original picture in the original size.

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is everything inside the `do {…}` printed?

Comment: Yes everything I do is inside there..

Comment: Yes everything is inside the do {…},I can see the file save locally but is just not the correct size